# Stick bootstrap text to the left

Tags: html, css, bulma

So I want to make a webpage with bulma/bootstrap and I want to stick some text to the left side of the screen.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UU3E.png)

So I want to add the text in the red area and I want it to remain there when I scroll down (like a side panel)

Answer (score 0):

Use the css properties `position: sticky` and `right: left: top: bottom:` to define the position of the red area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position